# How to delete row in go-sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, go

I'm using below code for adding two rows in table

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    database, _ := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./nraboy.db")
    statement, _ := database.Prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)")
    statement.Exec()
    statement, _ = database.Prepare("INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)")
    statement.Exec("Nic", "Raboy")
    statement, _ = database.Prepare("INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)")
    statement.Exec("Tom", "Hardy")
    _, err := statement.Exec("delete from people where id = 1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    rows, _ := database.Query("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM people")
    var id int
    var firstname string
    var lastname string
    for rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(&id, &firstname, &lastname)
        fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(id) + ": " + firstname + " " + lastname)
    }
}
```

but when I'm adding `_, err := statement.Exec("delete from people where id = 1")` for removing one of row I get following error:

```
2021/07/09 16:21:07 sql: expected 2 arguments, got 1
exit status 1
```

How to delete row in table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to call `statement, _ = database.Prepare("delete from people where id = 1")` for the delete command. When you are calling `statement.Exec("delete from people where id = 1")` the statement that was previously prepared is still in effect, and it expects two arguments (firstname, lastname).